# In Objective C, can you check if an object has a particular property or message?

Tags: objective-c

I wat to do something like this:

```
if (viewController.mapView) [viewController.mapView someMethod];
```

However, if mapView is not a class variable, this crashes. How do I check if mapView exists?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For ordinary selectors, you can use `respondsToSelector:`. I'm not certain if this will work for new-style property access (as it appears you are using in this example). To test if a class responds to a given selector, use `instancesRespondToSelector:`.

Comment: Property getter is a method with a name that matches the property and no arguments (i. e. no trailing colon in the signature).

Comment: Wow, Objective-C is not one to be concise is it?

Comment: @chaiguy: Objective-C is the furthest from concise as possible. Here's proof: [Longest Objective-C Method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15152232/2783780).

Answer (score 39):

Also, As Jason poninted out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1868761/296446), you can also use `NSSelectorFromString` to dynamically check at runtime.  E.g.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(elementName)]) 
{
    [self setValue:elementInnerText forKey:elementName];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as you intend it to... As stated by the NSSelectorFromString docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString "Note, therefore, that if the selector does not exist it is registered and the newly-registered selector is returned." Thus this `if` check will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @Stunner - Might have misunderstood but the docs seem to suggest that `NSSelectorFromString` always returns a SEL no matter if its implemented.  This is not a problem since `respondsToSelector:` does the actual checking we are interested in.

Comment: @Robert It's more than that. It means that if that particular selector does not exist *anywhere* in the program or the system, it will create a SEL for it. This is useful if you dynamically create methods based on user input. OTOH it is also a great way to get an app to use up all its memory if you wanna DoS it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950806/how-to-test-property-existence-and-type-based-on-nsstring-typed-key - you should check for the setter string `setMyProperty:` (note the : as well)

Answer (score 32):

Oops, found it:

```
if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView)]) {

  [[vc mapView] viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

Comment: You can also use it on synthesized property methods like `setMapView:`

Comment: or any property with an accessor and setter.  @property & @synthesize does most the work for you in most cases.  what i'm not sure about is if your getter isn't standard, for example @property (getter=notStandardGetter) NSString *aString;

Answer (score 0):

Here is more than you asked for but a category I have found useful to generically handle NSObject properties:

http://www.whynotsometime.com/Why_Not_Sometime/Category_Enhancing_NSObject.html