# how can you find out if an NSObject has a certain property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, weak-linking

Let's say in Apple API version 1.0, there is a class NSFoo with a property 'color'.  API 1.1 adds property 'size'.

I want to know whether I can use the getter: myFoo.size

[myFoo respondsToSelector:@selector(getSize)] doesn't work as expected.

What's the correct way to find out if an object has a property?  Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're close.  Your selector should be exactly the message you want to send to the object:

```
if ( [myFoo respondsToSelector:@selector(size)] ) {
    int size = [myFoo size]; // or myFoo.size in dot-notation.
    // ...
}
```

should work.

Comment: It should be noted that this is because the default getters for properties omit the `get` prefix. Unlike setters which have the `set` prefix.

Comment: How can I do it the other way around? If I want to set size on Foo? myFoo doesn't know the class properties so I can not access size.

Comment: @CristianPena I beleive if you changed "size" to "setSize" in the selector you could then call [myFood setSize:5].