# How to test property existence and type based on NSString typed key?

Tags: properties, css-selectors, exists, key-value-coding, objective-c-2.0

In my quest to update a Core Data model within my iOS project, I'm querying a server for JSON objects that correspond - to some extent - with the managed entities of my model. The end result I'm striving for is a reliable update solution from JSON output.

For the examples in this question, I'll name the core data managed object `existingObj` and the incoming JSON deserialized dictionary `updateDict`. The tricky part is dealing with these facts:

1. Not all properties of the `existingObj` are present in the `updateDict`
2. Not all properties of the `updateDict` are available in the `extistingObj`.
3. Not all types of `existingObj`'s properties match the JSON deserialized properties. (some strings may need a custom Objective-C wrapper).
4. `updateDict` may contain values for keys that are uninitialized (`nil`) in `existingObj`.

This means that while iterating through the updated dictionaries, there has to be some testing of properties back and forth. First I have to test whether the properties of the `updateDict` exist in `existingObj`, then I set the value using KVC, like so:

```
// key is an NSString, e.g. @"displayName"
if ([existingObj respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)) {
    [existingObj setValue:[updateDict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

Although this part works, I don't like the fact that I'm actually testing for `displayName` as a getter, while I'm about to call the `setDisplayName:` setter (indirectly via KVC). What I'd rather to is something like [existingObj <strike>hasWritablePropertyWithName</strike>:key], but something that does this I can't find.

**This makes for subquestion A: How does one test for a property setter, if you only have the property's name?**

The next part is where I'd like to automate the property identification based on their types. If both the `updateDict` and the `existingObj` have an NSString for key @"displayName", setting the new value is easy. However, if the `updateDict` contains an NSString for key @"color" that is @"niceShadeOfGreen", I'd like to transform this into the right UIColor instance. But how do I test the type of the receiving property in `existingObj` so I know when to convert values and when to simply assign? I was hoping for something along the lines of <strike>typeOfSelector:</strike>

```
if ([existingObj typeOfSelector:sel] == [[updateDict objectForKey:key] class]) {
     // regular assignment
} else {
     // perform custom assignment
}
```

Of course this is boguscode. I can't rely on testing the type of the `existingObj`-property's value, for it may be unitialized or `nil`.

**Subquestion B: How does one test for the type of a property, if you only have the property's name?**

I guess that's it. I figured this must be a dupe of something that's already on here, but I couldn't find it. Maybe you guys can?
Cheers, EP.

P.S. If you'd have a better way to synchronize custom Objective-C objects to deserialized JSON objects, please do share! In the end, the result is what counts.

Comment: I suggest you simply query `updateDict` for the keys *you know* and ignore all the rest.

Comment: From the example above, that's indeed a viable option. However in the real world scenario, this would make modifications to the managed object and updates very complex. The objects consist of over 30 keys/properties, most of which are NSString or NSNumber. If there is a solution to the question above, the synching would need no modification when primitive types are added or modified on both sides.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to query whether an object has a setter for a given KVC key called `key` which corresponds to a declared property, you need to check whether it responds to a selector method called `setKey:` (starts with `set`, capitalise the first character in `key`, add a trailing colon). For instance,

```
NSString *key = @"displayName";
NSString *setterStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@%@:",
                       [[key substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString],
                      [key substringFromIndex:1]];

if ([obj respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(setterStr)]) {
    NSLog(@"found the setter!");
    [obj setValue:someValue forKey:key];
}
```

Two remarks:

- Even though properties can have setters with names that do not follow the pattern described above, they wouldn’t be KVC compliant, so it is safe to check for `set<Key>:` since you’re using KVC to set the corresponding value.
- KVC doesn’t use the setter method only. If it doesn’t find a setter method, it checks whether the class allows direct access to instance variables and, if so, use the instance variable to set the value. Also, if no setter method or instance variable is found, it sends `-setValue:forUndefinedKey:` to the receiver, whose class might have overridden the standard implementation that throws an exception. This is described in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/SearchImplementation.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA).That said, if you’re always using properties, checking for the setter method should be safe.

As for your second question, it is not possible to query the runtime to know the actual Objective-C class of a property. From the runtime perspective, there’s an implementation specific type encoding for [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6) and [general types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1) (such as method parameters/return types). This type encoding uses a single encoding (namely `@`) for any Objective-C object, so the type encoding of an `NSString` property is the same as the type encoding of a `UIColor` property since they’re both Objective-C classes.

If you do need this functionality, one alternative is to process your classes and add a class method that returns a dictionary with keys and corresponding types for every property (or the ones you’re interested in) declared in that class and superclasses, or maybe some sort of description language. You’d have to do this on your own and rely on information not available during runtime.

Comment: Very valuable input @Bavarious. I didn't think of the dictionary with corresponding types, that's the most elegant solution sofar! Isn't this a common issue when updating a local model from server response in JSON? Are there better solutions to synching like that? Cheers, EP.

Comment: That would actually be a topic for a next question, I'll close this one for now. Thanks!

Comment: really cool, but how would this work (efficiently) for key paths?